# Swift - Override "refreshControl" property of ParseUI

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

Good day! I just want to ask if how can I add this [Custom pull to refresh](http://www.appcoda.com/custom-pull-to-refresh/) to my Swift project with Parse, I have a PFQueryTableViewController with `pullToRefreshEnabled` set to `true` so i get the default `Spinning Butthole` animation. I want to add the said Custom Pull to refresh animation. I tried doing the tutorial, but I'm getting an error `Cannot override mutable property 'refreshControl' of type 'UIRefreshControl?' with covariant type 'UIRefreshControl'` What should i do? Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried? What about posting some code to show where the error is?

Comment: when I'm adding a variable like this `var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()` i get this error `Cannot override mutable property 'refreshControl' of type 'UIRefreshControl?' with covariant type 'UIRefreshControl'`

Comment: Did you try following the instructions in the tutorial? It should be `var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!` and then in your `ViewDidLoad()` is where you set `refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()` where you would then add the `subView` to your `View`.

Comment: Yup, I cant run it because its giving me an error. It i use this `var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!` the error that I'm getting is this `Cannot override with a stored property 'refreshControl'`

Comment: You might have to give it a different name because I think the `PFQueryTableView` has that property already. Try `var customRefreshControl: UIRefreshControl!`

Comment: Yup it works now, But when I run it, I get this error on `customTbView.addSubview(customrefreshControl)` like this `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)`

Comment: Did you initialize it in `ViewDidLoad()`? `customRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()`. Of course this would be done before trying to `addSubview()`

Comment: I have this in my viewDidLoad, `customrefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
customrefreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
customrefreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
customTbView.addSubview(customrefreshControl)
loadCustomRefreshContents()`